# Word to define the following situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

There are 4 friends (F1, F2, F3, F4) talking about some random stuff and ended talking on a topic about a politician (Let's call him C). Among the four, one guy is a huge fan of C and ended up saying that C is a great person, so now the rest of three start saying that C is a great person in a passive tone. The last three spoke like that because, speaking in a negative tone about C will hurt the feelings of the others but in reality except for the first guy nobody likes C. Just because the first guy spoke positively the rest of three followed up. What do we call this phenomenon? How to describe this kind of situation?

Comment: To follow suit (from card games), or any of the following: copy someone
emulate someone
accord with someone
take your cue from someone
run with the herd                                              https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/follow-suit#follow-suit__1

Comment: Maybe the others were afraid that if they criticised the politician bad things might happen to them? I have a feeling I know who the 'politician' is.

Comment: In some cases they might be said to be telling a white lie (one told with good intentions).

Answer (score 1):

It is an example of "peer pressure".  This is the desire to conform to what a friend says or does, as [defined by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_pressure), this can be:

> The effect on an individual who is encouraged and wants to follow their peers by changing their attitudes, values or behaviors to conform to those of the influencing group or individual.

In your example, F1 has a positive attitude towards "C", and the three friends change their behaviour to conform with the values and attitudes of F1

Comment: It's not always peer pressure. For example the three people may agree because they feel very superior and see "fan of C" as a weak person who will be devastatingly upset if they disagree. That would not be peer pressure.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I think that is just an aspect of peer pressure. It doesn't have to be deliberate.  If the friends feel under social pressure to change their behaviour, because of pity, I think that's just a subtle form of pressure.

Comment: It may be pressure, but it's not by peers.

Comment: If this sort of pressure is induced by the society as a whole, then how do we define it?

Comment: As my comment says, I think it is a type of peer pressure, DJClayworth disagrees.  Though perhaps  "pressure from society" is "socail pressure".. In the context you give I think it is peer pressure

Comment: The situation the OP's describing isn't peer pressure, it's a combination of wanting to avoid hurting someone's feelings (which is sort of the opposite of being directly pressured by them), and also a misunderstanding where the others don't realise what's happening, take those "nice words" at face value, and do the same thing to avoid upsetting **that** person. So all the people who think X don't want to upset the person who thinks Y, and they all end up giving each other the impression that they all think Y

Answer (score 1):

If the 3 friends are pretending to like something to avoid hurting the other's feelings, they are **humoring** him.

See the definition of humor as a verb in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humoring): "to soothe or content (someone) by indulgence : to comply with the temperament or inclinations of"

Sorry that definition is a little hard to parse.  It means going along with someone just to avoid any conflict, difficulty, or annoyance that would follow from disagreeing with them.

Comment: From dictionary stand point, it makes sense. But I am still in search for more perspectives and answers. Thanks @Matt Timmermans for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a term that describes this phenomenon, that might be more of a question for a sociology forum to be honest! I feel like there are some parables/fables about this kind of thing too, where nobody's being honest (out of a genuine desire to do the right thing) and they all end up thinking they all believe X when they really all believe Y. The stories tend to be things like people who don't really enjoy a social situation pretend they do because they think their friends are enjoying themselves, but those friends are just pretending because they think the first friend is having fun, etc.

But I think your question is more about one person (who's an outlier) setting the agenda or the tone, and a consensus being established because everyone's too kind or polite or just unwilling to contradict that first outspoken person, and the effect snowballs from there because each person acquiescing makes the (non-existent) consensus seem stronger?

I'm just talking in case describing this gives you some ideas or avenues to look into, it definitely feels more like a sociology question to me - maybe something relating to collective behaviour.